# Can a docker instance be connected to just one specific network interface?

Tags: linux, docker

I have a server with two NICs, one for a private LAN between other servers (let's call it eth1) and one for public (let's call this one eth0).

I have a docker instance setup on the server for a client to host a website on. Is it possible to route network traffic out/in using just eth0? I do not want the client to be able to access the private lan.

If this is not possible, is there another solution?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That should be possible considering the kind of isolation [`docker network`](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/) is supposed to bring. You can even [define your own network](http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/dockernetworks/#user-defined-networks).

With a bridge network made on the server using eth0, you can define containers using only that network:

```
docker network create --driver bridge isolated_nw
docker run --net=isolated_nw -itd --name=container3 busybox
```

> The containers you launch into this network must reside on the same Docker host. Each container in the network can immediately communicate with other containers in the network. Though, the network itself isolates the containers from external networks.

[image: http://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/networking/images/bridge_network.png]